# Javascript popup in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
<div class="muuzgall">
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM muuzict_shows";
        $resultset = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) { ?>
            <div class="show">
                <a id="modalbtn<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/uploads/shows/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div id="myModal<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="modal">

          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="closee" id="close<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">&times;</span>
            <iframe src="https://tvstartup.biz/mng-channel/vpanel/vod_clappr.php?user=muuzictv&pass=07eae40bca0c91d0bb1f6b0be4924543&id=<?php echo $row['video_id']; ?>" seamless="seamless"  allowfullscreen="true"  scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" width="960" height="470" > </iframe>
          </div>

        </div>
        <script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal<?php echo $row['id']; ?>");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("modalbtn<?php echo $row['id']; ?>");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementById("close<?php echo $row['id']; ?>")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I am trying to get a popup to show for each of the `div.show` i loop out the popup with the div i want to show when clicked on, but when i click on the `div.show > a` it shows the very last popup looped
you can see a live example at https://muuzictyme.com

Comment: check console.log you have a number of errors in your code

Comment: @DCR okay checking now